How to replace a file path with whitespace using sed?
I have many different files with a string in them. I need to replace this string with a path, although the path contains whitespace. So far, I have this:
for a in files_[a-z][a-z]_all\.conf ; do

fileWithPath="~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass files_userpass.txt"
otherOne="auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt"

sed -i 's|'$otherOne'|'$fileWithPath'|g' $a

done

But I get

sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command

My question is how to replace this string correctly, with my path that has whitespace.
Thanks!

With space in the variable content, you should have them within double quotes ("). Now you use single quotes ('), and the variables are not within the quotes in the sed expression. Please try sed -i "s|$otherOne|$fileWithPath|g" "$a"

You don't need to escape the . in the for. While . is special in regular expressions, it is not special in file globs and this is a glob, so for a in files_[a-z][a-z]_all.conf works fine.

Your expression
's|'$otherOne'|'$fileWithPath'|g'

yields the unquoted string
s|auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt|~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass files_userpass.txt|g

which is then parsed into several words on the space characters.
The first of these,
s|auth-user-pass

is then passed to sed which rightly complains about the missing second | separator.
To pass the whole s command to sed as a single argument, you need to quote it. The easiest way to do that is to enclose the whole expression in double quotes:
"s|$otherOne|$fileWithPath|g"

The shell performs variable substitution within double quotes, so this will yield the quoted string
"s|auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt|~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass files_userpass.txt|g"

which will then be passed as a single argument to sed as intended.
It is good practice to enclose the filename argument $a in double quotes, too, to protect against space characters in the filename, although in your case it isn't strictly necessary since your pattern files_[a-z][a-z]_all\.conf won't match any filenames containing spaces.

+1 nice thorough answer - you might want to mention that the . in .conf doesn't need to be escaped (it's in a glob not a regex) and the otherOne and fileWithPath variable assignments don't need to be inside the loop

Your shell will split unquoted strings (resulting from parameter/variable expansion in your case) to words around value(s) in IFS ... See Word Splitting ... That is one thing.
Your shell may pass command-line arguments with modified quotes to the invoked program ... and that is another thing.
They say "Seeing something once is better than hearing about it a hundred times." and "Doing something once is better than seeing it a hundred times." ...
If you enable command traces in the Bash shell with set -x and then issue the sed command as you have it:
$ set -x
$
$ fileWithPath="~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass files_userpass.txt"
$ otherOne="auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt"
$
$ sed -i 's|'$otherOne'|'$fileWithPath'|g'
+ sed -i 's|auth-user-pass' 'mullvad_userpass.txt|~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass' 'files_userpass.txt|g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command

... you can see how your command-line is actually built and passed to the sed program and as you can see, your provided script is broken down into multiple parts (with quotes added) ... and as far as the sed program is concerned only the first set of matching quotes is considered as a script 's|auth-user-pass', and the following ones aren't even considered or added to the script since no -e is provided (to indicate nested commands, although -e requires syntactically correct commands to work) and therefore, indeed, the s command isn't terminated in that context ... hence the message:

sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command

Now, that you can see behind the scenes, compare the above to:
$ sed -i 's|'"$otherOne"'|'"$fileWithPath"'|g'
+ sed -i 's|auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt|~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass files_userpass.txt|g'
sed: no input files

or:
$ sed -i "s|$otherOne|$fileWithPath|g"
+ sed -i 's|auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt|~/Downloads/files_config_linux/auth-user-pass files_userpass.txt|g'
sed: no input files

... and that should be enough "seeing" and "doing" to figure out what's going on.
